# Knockout JS Spreadsheet Calc

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, knockout.js

I'm working on an HTML spreadsheet, using Knockout.js for data binding. I decided to go with a straightforward, albeit **graceless solution** that would allow me to better see and control what was happening on each binding, but even then I ran into a roadblock with two items: percentage and placing commas in resulting calculations.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WebMagi/NqBRT/

I managed to use:    `.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")` on the Total, but it broke the sheet when I added it to the two items (viewModel.C11 and viewModel.D11) giving me the total.

As for percentage, I'm trying to do the following: (C11-D11)/C11, which would be useful for showing a discount.

Anyone with ideas how to resolve these two issues?

Here is the Knockout code:

```
  var viewModel = {
  C1: ko.observable(24.37),
  C2: ko.observable(1.5),
  C3: ko.observable(""),
  C4: ko.observable("4"),
  C5: ko.observable("4"),
  C6: ko.observable("8"),
  C8: ko.observable(""),
  C9: ko.observable(""),
  C10: ko.observable(""),
  C11: ko.observable(""),
  C12: ko.observable(""),
  D1: ko.observable(38.62),
  D2: ko.observable(1.5),
  D3: ko.observable(""),
  D4: ko.observable("9"),
  D5: ko.observable("4"),
  D6: ko.observable("8"),
  D8: ko.observable(""),
  D9: ko.observable(""),
  D10: ko.observable(""),
  D11: ko.observable(""),
  D12: ko.observable(""),
  D13: ko.observable("")

};

viewModel.C3 = ko.computed(function () {
   return (this.C1() * this.C2()).toFixed(2);
}, viewModel);

viewModel.D3 = ko.computed(function () {
   return (this.D1() * this.D2()).toFixed(2);
}, viewModel);

viewModel.C8 = ko.computed(function () {
   return (this.C3() / this.C4()).toFixed(2);
}, viewModel);

viewModel.D8 = ko.computed(function () {
   return (this.D3() / this.D4()).toFixed(2);
}, viewModel);

viewModel.C9 = ko.computed(function () {
   return (this.C8() * this.C5()).toFixed(2);
}, viewModel);

viewModel.D9 = ko.computed(function () {
   return (this.D8() * this.D5()).toFixed(2);
}, viewModel);

viewModel.C10 = ko.computed(function () {
   return (this.C9() * this.C6()).toFixed(2);
}, viewModel);

viewModel.D10 = ko.computed(function () {
   return (this.D9() * this.D6()).toFixed(2);
}, viewModel);

viewModel.C11 = ko.computed(function () {
   return (this.C10() * 365).toFixed(2);
}, viewModel);

viewModel.D11 = ko.computed(function () {
   return (this.D10() * 365).toFixed(2);
}, viewModel);

//viewModel.C12 = ko.computed(function () {
//   return (this.C11() - this.D11()) / this.C11().toFixed(2);
//}, viewModel);

viewModel.D13 = ko.computed(function () {
   return (this.C11() - this.D11()).toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}, viewModel);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `(this.C11() - this.D11()) / this.C11().toFixed(2);` is that you are calling `toFixed` on a String. Surrounding the entire calculation in another set of parenthesis will fix the issue.

```
((this.C11() - this.D11()) / this.C11()).toFixed(2);
```

The reason you break the application by formatting `C11` and `D11` is that other computed observables are attempting to use the formatted return values in their calculations. Since `D13` has no other observables with a dependency on it, it works.

You'll need to provide a means to distinguish between calculation values and rendered/ formatted values. The quick and easy route is to provide a utility function on the model to perform the formatting.

```
viewModel.format = function(obs){
  return obs().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Html: `<span data-bind="text: format(C11)"></span>`

Comment: `return ((this.C11() - this.D11()) / this.C11() * 100).toFixed(2);` works perfectly. Thank you for that.

Comment: `viewModel.format(obs){
  return obs().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}` throws an error when added to the JS file. Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Fixed, not sure how that got messed up when I cut/paste from the fiddle after I modified it.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you.

I've updated the JSFiddle for use as needed: http://jsfiddle.net/WebMagi/NqBRT/

Comment: Looking at the same JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WebMagi/NqBRT/, viewModel.D13 is subtracting D11 from C11. What if I wanted to add these two formatted values instead (as in D11 + C11 = D13)? Changing - to + breaks the calculator. Any ideas?

Comment: The computed variables D11 and C11 are being converted to Strings by the `toFixed` calls and the '+' operation is performing a concatenation instead of addition. Either `parseFloat` the values back to numerics or extract the `toFixed` out of the calculation logic.

Comment: Now in modern browser (cf. < https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString>) you can do something as: return parseFloat(obs()).toLocaleString('en-US');